# Is it a good idea to use longtime Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a job list. Each job has its own run time. They need to run when it comes time. I think two different ways.

```
public class Job 
{
    public int JobPeriod {get;set;} // for example as hour: daily = 24, weekly = 7 * 24, monthly = 30 * 24 
    public DateTime RunTime {get;set}
}
```

First Way :

I start a new main thread. This thread checks jobs at certain time interval (5 sec, 10 sec etc.). When a job's run time  has come, the main thread will start and finish the job. The main thread which continually run in this way.

```
while (true)
{
   lock (Locker)
   {
       // checks job list.
       var jobs = foo.GetIncomingTimeJobs();
       foreach (var job in jobs)
       {
           ParameterizedThreadStart ts = RunJob;
           var th = new Thread(ts);
           th.Start(job);
       }

       Thread.Sleep(10000);
   }
}

public void RunJob(Job job)
{
   // do somethings
}
```

Second Way :

When application is started, I create a new thread for each job in the job list. All of these created threads will start. When Job's thread is started, job's thread checks the job's run time.

For example :

```
var jobs = foo.GetAllJobs();
foreach (var job in jobs)
{
      ParameterizedThreadStart ts = RunJob;
      var th = new Thread(ts);
      th.Start(job);
}

public void RunJob(Job job)
{
    while (true)
    {
       lock (Locker)
       {
           // do somethings
           var period = job.JobPeriod * 60 * 1000;
           Thread.Sleep(period);
       }
    }
}
```

If there are ten jobs , there will be ten threads. And These ten threads will never end.  will sleep, will continue, will sleep, will continue ...

Is it normal for threads to sleep such a long time ? Which way should I use ? Or Is there another way of doing such a thing?

Comment: Threads are expensive resources. Why don't you use a timer?

Comment: @nikie I want to use thread. No other reason.

Comment: @sinanakyazici - If you refuse to take our advice why are you here?  Why are you putting your main thread to sleep I see no benefit from doing so.  Your code is not effective and is prone to problems and I am speaking from experience.  At the very least you should use the 4.5 features like Task and others.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't mean that I do not care your ideas when I said "I want to use thread. No other reason". it is because I wonder is there a way to solve this problem with using threads. I don't know why I must use timer.

Comment: @sinanakyazici: Your code will most probably work, but calling Thread.Sleep() in most cases wastes **a lot** of processing time and power. Another reason not to do that is that sleeping thread is completely unresponsive to external events. For example, if you do Sleep on main GUI thread of WinForms application - this application will freeze for specified time and will not respond to any user actions.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev I understood. My application will run as a service. It is not forms application. So It needn't respond to any user actions.

Comment: User actions are only one of many possible events application should reposnse to. Service application, for example, should respond to service-specific events like service Start, service Stop etc. This could result in different errors like "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion." which can be quite complex to debug and fix.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev : thank you for answers. I will use timer. While I am using timer, What should I look? Do you have other suggestions ?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your last question? I don't quite get it :( If you were asking about what points are the most important in developing multi-threaded apps like yours, then I'd say synchronization, shared access to resources and proper finalizing. Keep your eye on shared resources usage (you already use `lock`, that's most simple way) and make sure your threads end as soon as they're not needed anymore.

Comment: Surely, 'Thread.Sleep() in most cases wastes a lot of processing time and power' is stretching things to breaking point since a sleeping thread takes none of either.  There is the argument that the extra stacks use memory and so may result in more swapping out while the other, running, threads do stuff, but it's not that important on most boxes/apps.  Of course, sleeping in GUI -handler threads that are expected to process messages in a timely manner  is a very bad idea, but this canoot be extended to non-GUI threads whre sleep() calls are ofen much more convenient and cheaper than a timer.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev : You used **The System.Threading.Timer** in your answer. However, according to article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S2) **The System.Timers.Timer** safer than **The System.Threading.Timer**.  What is your opinion ?

Comment: If you don't plan to access timer members from job threads then it doesn't really matter. Otherwise System.Timers.Timer might be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both approaches are in most cases incorrect. Usual solution for this kind of problems is using [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). Sample code for your case can look like that:

```
private void CheckJobs(object state)
{
    lock (Locker)
    {
        // checks job list.
        var jobs = foo.GetIncomingTimeJobs();
        foreach (var job in jobs)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(foo);
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}

private void StartProcessing()
{
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(CheckJobs, null, 0, 10000);
}
```

When you call StartProcessing() function, the timer will be initialized and jobs list will be checked every 10 seconds.

If you go with Thread.Sleep() your application will become very unresponsive.